# Perl syntax colouring

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

I'm aware that Perl is (intentionally, just like English) particularly awkward to parse, and so its automatic syntax colouring can be very wrong

But while I expect to see the colouring engine thrown by a mismatched string delimiter in the middle of a regular expression, I am recently (20-Jul-2015) seeing extremely minimal colouring that I can't explain

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31521514/622310) is an example. It is very ordinary Perl, but has all of my code in black except for language words (`use`, `my`, `print`) in #00008b and (inexplicably) dull blue #2b91af for `Mechanize` in `use WWW::Mechanize` and `UserAgent` in `use LWP::UserAgent`

I understood that the colouring was done by a Google engine, and if that is true then I would like more details. As things stand I would prefer my code to be uncoloured, and I wonder if I have to start adding `language: lang-none` comments to my posts?

Comment: I'm seeing string literals highlighted in red on that post...are those also black for you?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Yes, everything is black other than what I have described. I am seeing the same on both Firefox and Chrome. Is it possible that you're seeing Meta CSS on SO posts if you click the link?